# Teamviewer Risks When Connecting to Another Computer

Tags: teamviewer

Are there any risks to be aware of if you remote into another person's computer via their Teamviewer Partner ID and password?

Any recommended settings to choose when remoting into an unknown computer?

All of the searches I have tried focus on the risks of allowing someone to access your computer, but I'm curious if there is anything one should watch out for if you are accessing someone else's computer.

For example, I saw one comment that depending on your settings, the host computer may receive what is in your clipboard (which may be username or password info if you use a password manager).

The context is a potential client that I have never worked with before has asked me to do Excel work on their computer. They don't want to send the file, they want to send me their Teamviewer Partner ID and password so I can do the work on their computer via Teamviewer. And out of an abundance of caution I want to make sure I am not unwittingly giving them access to my computer or files.

Comment: In theory, the destination computer could exploit the computer via a vulnerability in TeamViewer that's connecting to it. That kind of thing has happened in the past.